# Поиск методов в списке C#

Tags: c#, list, поиск, методы

Есть список `List<MethodInfo>` с записанными в него методами. Надо выполнить поиск по списку(по свойству MethodInfo.Name), чтобы потом получить нужный MethodInfo и запустить его через Invoke;

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: В идеале хотелось бы получить ту строку кода(или блок), которая сможет выполнить поиск в списке и вернуть результат(не важно MethodInfo или номер элемента)

Comment: @Regent, Я уже ищу вопрос-дубликат :-)

Comment: Давай, если что у меня есть щит https://hkar.ru/PDko :)

Comment: А `List.Find` вам чем не нравится?

Comment: `Давай, если что у меня есть щит hkar.ru/PDko :)` - еще один попался на крючок))

Comment: Хехе, баннер - есть баннер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var consoleType = typeof(Console);
var methods = new List<MethodInfo>(consoleType.GetMethods());
string wantedMethodName = "WriteLine";
```

1) Можно сделать простой перебор списка и забрать первый элемент, удовлетворяющий условию:

```
MethodInfo findedMethod;
foreach (var method in methods)
{
    if (method.Name == wantedMethodName)
    {
        findedMethod = method;
        break;
    }
}
```

2) Или воспользоваться методами LINQ, что сделает код проще и симпатичнее:

```
var findedMethod = methods.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == wantedMethodName);
```

или

```
var findedMethod = methods.Find(m => m.Name == wantedMethodName);
```

Об отличиях `FirstOrDefault` и `Find` можете прочесть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault).

Answer (score -1):

```
private MethodInfo FindMethodInfo(string name)
{
    return MethodInfoList?.Where(r => r.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Поправил, как подсказал @teanЫЧ

Comment: можно просто `first` одна из перегрузок принимает делегат

Comment: return MethodInfoList?.Where(r => r.Name == name).FirstOrDefault(); Но если человек не понимает, как пробежаться по списку и найти нужный элемент, я бы не стал ему приводить в качестве примера LINQ, ибо в глазах неподготовленных людей, он выглядит непостижимой магией. Тут уж лучше через обычный цикл сделать все.

Comment: Главное, что работает

Comment: Нет, главное, чтобы вы понимали, КАК это работает.

Comment: Я узнал о существовании Where. Вроде как догадываюсь, что он возвращает те элементы, где указанные свойства равны каким либо значениям. И то что First() возвращает первый элемент :)

Comment: @Morkoffka, тут не нужен where, можно одним `first` или `firstordefault` обойтись в случае, если искомый элемент может отсутствовать

Comment: `MethodInfoList.Where(r => r.Name == name).Count() > 0` зачем считать все элементы, если нужно просто проверить наличие?

Comment: просто не знаю, как с помощью list.find указать поиск по свойству name?

Comment: @Grundy  Он хочет найти конкретный MethodInfo и потом запустить, а не просто проверить наличие : _чтобы потом получить нужный MethodInfo  и запустить его через Invoke_

Comment: Не надо Where(predicat).Count() > 0, достаточно Any(predicat). Дважды вызывать Where грех, делать First else null ещё более грешно, есть FirstOrDefault. На то вам и Linq, что бы лаконично выражать то, что вы хотите, тут вместо функции достаточно выражения `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name)?.Invoke(...)`

Comment: Ещё, ещё лаконичней, FirstOrDefault может принимать предикат, Where не нужен

Comment: @koshe, какому из моих комментариев это противоречит?

Comment: _зачем считать все элементы, если нужно просто проверить наличие?_ это Вы писали.

Comment: @koshe, это относилось к `Count() > 0` и тут ты именно и делал, что проверял, что _что-то_ есть